# How can U.S. prevent counterfeit if the U.S. dollar bills have no expiry date?

Tags: united-states, money-market, counterfeiting

Counterfeit bills are a big problem for governments, so they periodically update their bills to add several security features aimed at preventing counterfeit bills.

But I imagine that for this to work, the old bills need to be removed from circulation, for example by setting an expiry date after which they can't be converted to newer bills and lose validity.

How do countries whose bills *don't* have an expiry date handle counterfeit? What prevents an expert counterfeit from printing money from the 1950's (which the government themselves believe to be insecure now) and making a profit? I believe that this is the case of the U.S., since the U.S. dollar bills do not have an expiry date.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, I am not talking about the viability of counterfeit *in general*. Since governments have deemed necessary updating bills with new security features, you should work with the assumption that counterfeit without those new security features is (or will become in about 10 years) feasible and profitable. So any explanation that applies to counterfeit in general (like matching serial bills, say) is automatically invalid.

Comment: Just another source of Quantitative Easing?

Comment: I feel like if I saw a bunch of new $100 bills from the 50's I would have an eyebrow or two raised? Unless you're assuming they have a mechanism to print new ones and then wear them down?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with _Personal_ Finance and Money.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I know it's probably a joke but comparing counterfeting money to Quantitative easing is simply ridicolous :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad Sure, but there are lots of banks in the states. It wouldn't be hard to acquire millions of dollars this way, unless a systematic check is done aggregating informations

Comment: @Ant: I don't understand what you're saying. There could be 1 banks or 1 million banks, I don't see what that has to do with what I said. Whoever receives new "old" money will get suspicious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because counterfeiting is a legal problem, not a PF issue.

Comment: @Mehrdad If your entire security is based on the fact that you can tell which bills look old and which don't, you should be worried. Also experts can make "new" money look old, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @ant you're missing that the bills are tracked with serial numbers. An average person won't know they're faked, but a bank will inevitably catch on. That and the things the others said. The countermeasures for conterfeiting are added with each bill, and of course are different based on the size of the bill. Your question about *old* bills is interesting; I think the answer that mentions banks destroying old bills addresses it somewhat well. But aside from that, *bills have serial numbers.* You could mark a bill as having been at one specific location, or been destroyed, and catch fakes of it.

Comment: @schizoid04: How could you possibly do that?  You would have to equip every person or business that might receive cash with a device to scan serial numbers, and look them up in a database.  Meanwhile, the intelligent counterfeiter also has one of these databases, and prints bills with valid serial numbers.  The people who hold those bills are probably SOL after the counterfeit is presented.

Comment: @schizoid04 Apart from what jamesqf said, *you're missing the point*. You are talking about counterfeit in general, and I am not. If serial bills were enough to prevent counterfeit, then you don't need new bills with new security features. Since you do, it means serial numbers are not enough.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Can you suggest a stack exchange site where this would be more appropriate?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Questions about how currency works are inherently related to personal finance.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting thought. I think (at least) two things would help to foil a counterfeiters. 1. He'd have to not only duplicate the bills, but then make them look old. So there's an extra challenge. If you tried to give someone a bill dated 1950 and it looked new, that would be likely to arouse some suspicion. And 2. If someone went to the bank or wherever with a stack of bills all dated 100 years ago, that would surely attract attention.

In general I think the goal of counterfeiters is to pass their bills unnoticed. If you can hand someone your fake bill and they don't think about it but just accept it, you win. If they get suspicious or cautious for any reason and start looking carefully, they're liable to see the flaws.

And of course the flip side is that if bills did have an expiration, what happens to someone who tries to tuck some money away for emergencies? He may find that that money he stuffed in the shoe box 20 years ago has now expired. Someone who wasn't aware of the law or didn't think about it could accidentally lose a fortune overnight. Even if the expiration period is long, it's not like everyone who handles the bill has that amount of time. Suppose the expiration was 20 years, like in Switzerland (sort of). For the first person to get the bill, fine, he has 20 years to spend it. But what happens to the poor guy who gets the bill when it's 19 1/2 years old? If he doesn't notice and let's it sit in his wallet or whatever for six months, suddenly he's out the money. Indeed, depending on how the system worked, it might mean that every time you received cash, you would have to go through every bill and check that it wasn't expired, or about to expire very soon. You couldn't just stuff change in your pocket: you'd have to carefully check each bill. Plus you'd have to have a mechanism for people to trade in old bills and get them replaced with new bills, which would surely be at least a nuisance.

So it seems to me that the question is whether the risk of counterfeits outweighs the unfairness of destroying the value of people's cash, or at the very least imposing inconvenience on handling money. I suppose if a country had major problems with counterfeiters, they might be forced to do this.

Comment: Uhm I am not completely convinced. For the first thing, I imagine it's not that hard for an expert to make a bill look old. For the second, you can go a bank and say "Look! I found in my grandaparent's attic 20k dollars! Can you put it in my account please?". The bank would check the bills, but they would pass inspection. Now rinse and repeat to other, far away branches. 
(Also, by the time the bill is 19 1/2 years old, you *would* notice it. I live in switzereland, and last year they introduced new 50 CHF bills. I hardly see any of the old ones anywhere now)

Comment: My point about taking a stack of old bills to the bank was, they would likely be inspected. If a counterfeiter tried to make a batch of 100-year-old-looking bills and take them to the bank, it's likely someone would notice and they would get inspected.

Comment: It seems to me that it is unlikely that you could look at a bill and instantly see that it is 19 years old rather than 17 or 21. The amount of wear would depend on many factors. And that's my point: you'd have to constantly pay attention to the expiration date on the bills. BTW I said "sort of" on Switzerland because it's not like every bill in Switzerland expires 20 years after it's printed. As I understand it, they expire 20 years after a new series comes out. So the old bills presumably look recognizably different. Maybe that's an important element to make an expiration scheme work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with "you would notice". When a new series comes out, the bills look noticeably different, so you can't really go wrong. Same thing with the euro bills.

Comment: "t's likely someone would notice and they would get inspected" -- sure, I don't disagree. But it doesn't seem like the best protection ever, especially since U.S. dollar bills are visually identical (correct me if I'm wrong). I mean, banks would get suspiscious of *anyone* coming in to change 20k dollars in cash. That doesn't mean we don't use try to curb counterfeit money by adding special security features.

Comment: @Ant: I'll ask the opposite question: How can you trust the money if it expires?  Indeed, I've got a few hundred in Euros and CHF sitting around since my last trip: do I have to worry that they'll evaporate?  I'll also point out that US currency seems at least as acceptable as those, worldwide, so the lack of expiration dates obviously can't be presenting a major problem.

Comment: "How can you trust money if it expires" - Well, entire nations do, so I guess it's not a big deal. In 20 years you will most likely have zero bills of the old denomination. And what percentage of your wealth is in cash, anyway? -- " so the lack of expiration dates obviously can't be presenting a major problem" I absolutely agree, that's why I asked the question in the first place. *Why* is it not a problem? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you deposit money in a bank, the bank teller (the person who processes the deposit) takes the cash and puts it in a cash counting machine.  The machine is entirely capable of doing any number of checks on the money.  In particular, it can check that the paper is the type of paper on which money is printed (as opposed to, say, copier paper).  And yes, the machine can systematically aggregate information with other machines.

One of the big problems with counterfeiting money is getting good paper.  One solution to that was to take $1 bills, bleach them, and print higher denominations on them.  With the new money, the $1 bills have unbleachable marks in them.  So the bill may look like a $20 bill to the eye but actually recognized by the machine as a $1 bill masquerading as a $20.

Yes, the criminals could continue using old $1 bills printed to look like old $20 bills.  But the $1 bills are increasingly scarce.  Because any bill older than about three years gets sent back to the Treasury department to be replaced.  So they don't have an inexpensive source for old $1 bills.

A bank would almost certainly catch a counterfeit bill at the time of deposit because the equipment is designed for that.  The greater problem is that someone may pass counterfeits somewhere other than a bank.  The typical Wal-Mart does not have the same kind of counting equipment.  But it's harder to pass large numbers of bills at a Wal-Mart.  They only take moderate amounts at a time, say $500 for a really large order.

The initial purchase will almost certainly be successful.  But after the initial purchase, surveillance video will show who made the $500 purchase with cash.  They'll be on the lookout for more counterfeits.

So for $500 in merchandise, the counterfeiter paid $25 or more to get the $1 bills.  Had to find the old $1 bills, when most are newer than that.  Paid more money to do the counterfeiting.  And can't sell the $500 merchandise for $500 but probably more like $250 after costs.  And can't scale things up because a repeat visit is much more likely to be caught.  A $200 profit on a counterfeiting event is not that much.  They really need more money for it to be profitable compared to other illegal things that they might do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me though that what you says applies to counterfeiting in general, and does not really address my question.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jay's excellent answer...

> the old bills need to be removed from circulation, for example by setting an expiry date
>   How do countries whose bills don't have an expiry date handle counterfeit?

Paper money wears out, and old bills get pulled out of by banks, then sent to the Fed for shredding/burning.

More importantly, a 1957 US $1 bill would have been:

1. a Silver Certificate, which would mightily confuse retailers and bank tellers, and
2. only made in $1, $5 and $10 denominations, so trying to pass them off as $20 or $50 or $100 bills would be known as fakes with a little research.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_certificate_(United_States)

> The small-size silver certificate (1928–1964) was only regularly issued in denominations of $1, $5, and $10.

[image]

Comment: Please do not [answer a question and also vote to close](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2149/10997). Either retract your close vote, or delete your answer.

Comment: I don't understand your point #2.  $1 silver certificates were issued only in $1 denominations, not $5 or $10.  Federal Reserve notes were also in circulation at that time, in denominations ranging up to $10,000, so the "only $1, $5, and $10 denominations" can't be an attempt to describe all bills in circulation.  Although, the image you post is very helpful for displaying that even people not normally attentive to currency design would notice something off about many bills from the 1950's.

Comment: @user4556274 I'm quoting Wikipedia.  Evidence of only $1 denominations is always welcome.

Comment: Well, 1950's were just an example - take bills from the 1970s then

Comment: @Ant I'd question whether or not there enough bills remaining in circulation to make it worth all the effort.

Comment: But why do you need the bills to be in circulation? You're faking them, after all. You create bills now, that *look like* the ones from the 1970s, go to a bank and ask to put it in your account. The bank will test the bills but they will pass the test since security features in the 1970s are outdated. What's wrong with this scenario?

Comment: @Ant "*But why do you need the bills to be in circulation?*" That was the scenario mentioned in the Question. "*You create bills now, that look like the ones from the 1970s*"  That's a *different* question...  :)  It would require extra effort to make them look old, and questions would be raised about where all this 40 year old money came from (because small-scale counterfeiting is unprofitable).

Comment: Hi, so there was a misunderstanding :-) with "What prevents an expert counterfeit from printing money from the 1950" I meant "new money that looks from the 1950". If you have access to actual money from the 1950s, then why do you counterfeit them in the first place ;-) " 40 year old money came from" Sure, but what prevents me from going to 20-30 different branches in different states, and bringin 20k found in my grandad attic? :)